# aggregate over multiple columns

Tags: r

Hey I have some data looks like this:

```
ExpNum  Compound Peak Tau SS
1        a       100  30  50
2        a       145  23  45
3        b       78   45  56
4        b       45   43  23
5        c       344  23  56
```

Id like to fund the mean based on Compound name 
What I have

```
Norm_Table$Norm_Peak = (aggregate(data[[3]],by=list(Compound),FUN=normalization))
```

This is fine and I have this coding repeating 3 times just changing the data[[x]] number. Would lapply work here? or a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(Compound) %>%
  summarize_each(funs(mean), -ExpNum)
```

Comment: OP may want to exclude the `ExpNum` from the solution.  I think you can change this to do `summarize_each(funs(mean), -ExpNum)`.

Comment: Most likely yes, I agree!

Comment: Can i include ExpNum in the Group_by? So it does it based on two factors? If I only want columns 3-6 could I use data[,3:6] as well?

Comment: Yes, then you get `data %>%
  group_by(Compound, ExpNum) %>%
  summarize_each(funs(mean))`

Comment: Sorry for all the of questions here, does the funs() argument not like personalized functions? and a more generic question is what exaclt is the %>% I've been seeing it a lot lately.

Comment: `summarize_each(funs(normalization))` should work if it outputs one value per vector you put in. `%>%` is a pipe operator, see `?'%>%'`. Basically `f(x, y)` is equal to `x %>% f(y)`, which can be useful when chaining many functions.